# How to pass an object to onSubmit in React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

When using `react-hook-form` I need to pass arbitrary data into the `onSubmit` function.  Example code:

```
function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const navigation = { foo: 'bar' }; // object to pass
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    // how to access navigation here?
    console.log(data);
    console.log(navigation); // undefined
  }; 
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}> // <<== pass navigation here as arg? 
      <input defaultValue="test" {...register("example")} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

How can I pass my object `navigation` into `onSubmit`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`handleSubmit(onSubmit)` means that you're passing `onSubmit` by reference and it's taking the `data` by default , call the `handleSubmit` like this :

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => onSubmit(data, navigation))}>
```

and the object should be available here :

```
const onSubmit = (data, obj) => {
  console.log(data, obj);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do smth like this.

```
const onSubmit = (obj) => (formData) => { 
  console.log(obj);
};

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit(obj))}> // your obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess that the navigation props is received by the App Component (like a prop) and then you can pass it to the onSubmit method.

try this:

```
"onSubmit={()=>handleSubmit(props.navigation)}"
```

here an explample https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/